# Parallel c code using pthreads.h uses less than 100%CPU and is slower when using more threads

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, pthreads, conways-game-of-life

So I have a project where I needed to implement the game of life and then parallelise it in c. However, when I try using pthreads.h to parallelise it the program runs slower when introducing more threads and the %CPU is lower than 100% (when using top in the ubuntu terminal, I have an Ubuntu Windows subsystem). Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

/*  Parallel code with PTHREADS v1 */

//Global variables 
int N;          // Size of the world
int nthreads;   // Number of threads
pthread_mutex_t lock;

typedef struct info_thread
{
    int threadID;       // thread ID
    int low;            // lower limit of interval
    int high;           // higher limit of interval
    int **world;        // pointer to the world matrix
    int **neighbors;    // pointer to the neighbors matrix
    //int **neighbors_2;  // pointer to the neighbors_2 matrix
    //int **one_step;     // pointer to the one_step matrix
}t_info;

void * thread_func(void *arg);
void print_world(int **world);
void count_neighbors(int **world, int **neighbors);
void next_step(int **world, int **one_step, int **neighbors);
void update(int **world, int **one_step);
int compare(int **world, int **one_step, int **two_steps, int **old, int status);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 5)
    {
        printf("Give the following input arguments:\n");
        printf("N: Size of the NxN world (integer)\n");
        printf("Initial state: random (0), chessboard (1)\n");
        printf("Output: Number of steps until final state (0) \n");
        printf("        Number of steps until final state, initial and final states (1) \n");
        printf("        Number of steps until final state and all states states (2) \n");
        printf("Threads: Number of threads (integer)\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    const int pattern = atoi(argv[2]);
    const int output = atoi(argv[3]);
    nthreads = atoi(argv[4]);

    // Create necessary matrices
    const int n = N+1;
    int **buffer = (int **)malloc(6 * n * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i = 0; i < (6*n); i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }

    int **world = &buffer[0];
    int **neighbors = &buffer[n];
    int **neighbors_2 = &buffer[2*n];
    int **one_step = &buffer[3*n];
    int **two_steps = &buffer[4*n];
    int **old = &buffer[5*n];

    // Setting a random initial pattern
    if(pattern == 0){
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                int r = rand() % 10;
                if (r > 5)
                    world[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    world[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // Setting a chessboard initial state
    else if(pattern == 1){
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if(i%2 == 0){
                    if(j%2 == 0)
                        world[i][j] = 0;
                    else
                        world[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else{
                    if(j%2 == 0)
                        world[i][j] = 1;
                    else
                        world[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(output==1 || output==2){
        printf("Initial state:\n");
        print_world(world);
    }
    
    int status = 1;
    int t = 1;
    update(old, world);

    // Create threads and input info
    pthread_t thread[nthreads];
    t_info threadinfo[nthreads];
    const int interval = N/nthreads;

    while(status == 1)
    {
        for (int k=0; k<nthreads; k++)
        {
            threadinfo[k].threadID = k;
            threadinfo[k].low = k*interval;
            threadinfo[k].high = (k+1)*interval-1;
            threadinfo[k].world = world;
            threadinfo[k].neighbors = neighbors;
        }
        threadinfo[nthreads-1].high = N;

        // Predict one step forward
        pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
        for (int k=0; k<nthreads; k++)
            pthread_create(&thread[k], NULL, thread_func, (void *)&threadinfo[k]);
        for (int k=0; k<nthreads; k++)
            pthread_join(thread[k],NULL);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
        next_step(world, one_step, neighbors);
        
        // Predict two steps forward
        for (int k=0; k<nthreads; k++)
        {
            threadinfo[k].world = one_step;
            threadinfo[k].neighbors = neighbors_2;
        }
        for (int k=0; k<nthreads; k++)
            pthread_create(&thread[k], NULL, thread_func, (void *)&threadinfo[k]);
        for (int k=0; k<nthreads; k++)
            pthread_join(thread[k],NULL);
        
        //count_neighbors(one_step,neighbors_2);
        next_step(one_step, two_steps, neighbors_2);

        // Compare all predicted steps
        status = compare(world, one_step, two_steps, old, status);
        
        // Update world with two steps
        update(world, two_steps);

        
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j+=2)
            {
                neighbors[i][j] = 0;
                neighbors[i][j+1] = 0;
                neighbors_2[i][j] = 0;
                neighbors_2[i][j+1] = 0;
            }
        }

        if((output == 2) && (status == 1)){
            printf("Step %d:\n", t);
            print_world(one_step);
            printf("Step %d:\n", t+1);
            print_world(two_steps);
        }
        
        // Save previous step
        update(old, world);
        //t+=1;
        t+=2;
    }

    //printf("It took %d steps to reach the final state\n", t-2);
    printf("It took %d steps to reach the final state\n", (t-3));
    if(output==1 || output ==2){
        printf("Final state:\n");
        print_world(world);
    }    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (6*n); i++)
    {
        free(buffer[i]);
    }
    free(buffer);
}

void * thread_func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    t_info *threadinfo = arg;
    int threadID = threadinfo->threadID;
    int low = threadinfo->low;
    int high = threadinfo->high;
    //int **world = threadinfo->world;
    //int **neighbors = threadinfo->neighbors;

    int i; //rows
    int j; //col
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++){
        for (j = 0; j <= N-1; j++){     
            if (i > 0){
                if (j > 0){
                    if (threadinfo->world[i-1][j-1] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (j < N-1){
                    if (threadinfo->world[i-1][j+1] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (threadinfo->world[i-1][j] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
            if (i < N-1){
                if (j > 0){
                    if (threadinfo->world[i+1][j-1] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (j < N-1){
                    if (threadinfo->world[i+1][j+1] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (threadinfo->world[i+1][j] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
            if (j > 0){
                if (threadinfo->world[i][j-1] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
            if(j < N-1){
                if (threadinfo->world[i][j+1] == 1)
                        threadinfo->neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void print_world(int **world)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j+=2)
        {
            printf("%d ", world[i][j]);
            printf("%d ", world[i][j+1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");   
}

void count_neighbors(int **world, int **neighbors)
{
    int i; //rows
    int j; //col
    for (i = 0; i <= N-1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j <= N-1; j++){     
            if (i > 0){
                if (j > 0){
                    if (world[i-1][j-1] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (j < N-1){
                    if (world[i-1][j+1] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (world[i-1][j] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
            if (i < N-1){
                if (j > 0){
                    if (world[i+1][j-1] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (j < N-1){
                    if (world[i+1][j+1] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
                }
                if (world[i+1][j] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
            if (j > 0){
                if (world[i][j-1] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
            if(j < N-1){
                if (world[i][j+1] == 1)
                        neighbors[i][j] +=1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void next_step(int **world, int **one_step, int **neighbors)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if (world[i][j] == 1)
            {
                if (neighbors[i][j] == 2 || neighbors[i][j] == 3)
                    one_step[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    one_step[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else if (world[i][j] == 0)
            {
                if (neighbors[i][j] == 3)
                    one_step[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    one_step[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void update(int **world, int **one_step)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j+=2)
        {
            world[i][j] = one_step[i][j];               
            world[i][j+1] = one_step[i][j+1];
        }
            
    }
}

int compare(int **world, int **one_step, int **two_steps, int **old, int status)
{
    int counter1=0, counter2=0, counter3=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if(world[i][j] == one_step[i][j])
                counter1++;
            if(world[i][j] == 0)
                counter2++;
            if(old[i][j] == two_steps[i][j])
                counter3++;
        }
    }
    if (counter1 == (N*N))
        status = 0;
    else if(counter2 == (N*N))
        status = 0;
    else if(counter3 == (N*N))
        status = 0;
    return status;
}
```

When I compile the code and run it using 2, 4 and 8 threads I get the following:

```
gcc -o gol gol.c -lpthread
time ./gol 500 1 0 2
It took 1670 steps to reach the final state

real    0m10.064s
user    0m8.971s
sys     0m0.246s
time ./gol 500 1 0 4
It took 1670 steps to reach the final state

real    0m15.694s
user    0m9.976s
sys     0m0.437s
time ./gol 500 1 0 8
It took 1670 steps to reach the final state

real    0m14.600s
user    0m10.400s
sys     0m0.855s
```

Also the %CPU using top is ~65% when using 2 threads, ~78% when using 4 threads and ~100% when using 8 threads. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you reduce the code? Surely it's not needed to have an entire program emulating Conway's game of life to asses whether the problem is the threading or not... you can use a much simpler operation of just a handful of lines of code to test.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to include your processor reference in the question as well as the compiler/compilation-flags you use.

Comment: I do not see the point of a thread function that is structured 'lock; DoStuff; unlock;'.  You may as well just call the function:(

Comment: ... and that explains why the parallel version is slower.  You get no concurrency, but you still have the overhead from multithreading generally and from managing mutexes in particular.  That before even considering whether you are performing redundant computations.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am sure it is possible to reduce the code however I am a beginner in c thus I didnt no of any other way to impelement this. The program worked fine before introducing the threading

Comment: @JérômeRichard I tried to first see if it run faster without any compiler flags so I compiled it exactly the way I mentioned! I have an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265 CPU processor

Comment: @JohnBollinger This was something I found here on Stack and just tried it out

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 problems:

a) Creating threads and waiting for them to terminate adds overhead. Doing it inside a "`while(status == 1)`" loop means that you're paying for that extra overhead repeatedly. It'd be better to create the threads once (outside the loop) then re-use the existing threads, using something (e.g. condition variable) to make the threads wait for the next iteration of the loop.

b) Mutexes exist to prevent (unwanted) parallelism, and also have overhead. If the threads acquire a mutex, then do their work, then release a mutex; then you're deliberately preventing all parallelism between these threads. For your code, parallelism between the main thread and the newly created threads is also prevented (main thread sits waiting in a `pthread_join()`).

Essentially; you've added lots of overhead (creating and destroying threads, acquiring and releasing mutexes) and prevented all parallelism to ensure that there's no benefits to outweigh the extra overhead; leading to code that is worse than not using threads at all.

To fix this you need to find ways to ensure that threads can do useful work in parallel. The easiest way to do that would probably be to use 2 global arrays to represent the state of the world, where one of these arrays is "previous world state" and the other is "next world state", and where you swap (pointers to) the arrays between steps. In this case, during a step, "previous world state" is only being read (and many threads can read in parallel without a problem) and each thread can update different parts of "next world state" in parallel. Note that because the threads would write to each cell in "next world state" you won't need to clear "next world state" between steps either.

*WARNING: To ensure that updating one element of the array won't cause "lack of atomicity" problems with other/adjacent elements in the array; you will need to either use an atomic type (`sig_atomic_t`, C11 I think) with a 2D array, or use "1D array of pointers to 1D arrays" (where each row can only be modified by one thread) and the element/s are `volatile`. Note that if the world state is an 8 * 8 grid you can probably represent a whole row with a single `uint8_t` (meaning that it could become "1D array of pointers to `volatile uint8_t`).*

Basically (if you include the re-use of threads) it can be done without using any mutexes for anything other than worker threads waiting for the main thread to start the next step, and the main thread waiting for worker threads to complete the current step.

Also; instead of waiting for worker threads, the main thread can also participate in doing useful work. For example, if the world state is an 8 * 8 grid, then "main thread + 7 worker threads" can do a row each (in parallel) to ensure that all 8 rows are done. However, when threads have the same priority it's rarely sane to have more threads than CPUs; so it can be a good idea to check how many CPUs the computer has and limit the number of threads (e.g. if there are 4 CPUs, then you might have "main thread + 3 more threads do 2 rows each").

Comment: If the OP follows your double-buffering approach -- which is a good idea -- then the synchronization required to properly coordinate the switch from one generation to the next will be sufficient for protecting access to both the old-state and the new-state buffers.  The elements to not need to be atomic.  Also, `sig_atomic_t` is not (necessarily) atomic in the sense that is required for shared access without synchronization.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: As far as I know, for array elements atomicity is "implementation defined". E.g. for an array of `char` or `uint8_t`, on some CPUs a write of one byte may need to be broken up into a "read, modify, write" of a larger area (e.g. because the CPU itself only supports larger accesses).